# Differential equation: general solution for formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have following formula and I need the general solution:

$$
\frac{d^{2}\theta}{d\xi ^{2}}-\mu ^{2}\cdot \theta =0
$$

**EDIT**

Following solution was given:
$$
\theta(\xi )=C_{1}\cdot exp(\mu \xi ))+C_{2}\cdot exp(-\mu \xi ))
$$

**EDIT #2**

I came to a solution by using this method: http://statistik.wu-wien.ac.at/~leydold/MOK/HTML/node185.html

Is this solution the easiest?

Comment: You mark this as a pde,  yet use the regular deriviatve notation...is $\theta$ a multivalued function?   what is $\mu$, a constant or a function or...?

Comment: As far as I know, no functions just constants.

Comment: @alan: Someone suggested to change my before given tags to pde. I am from Germany, so I am not familiar with this English names :)

Comment: @susan WIth that solution set and that problem,  $\mu$ is definatitely a constant, and this is an ODE: Ordinary Differential Equation, as opposed to PDE: Partial Differential Equation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\mu$ is not a function of $\theta$ or $\xi$, this equation is separable.

$$\frac{d^{2}\theta}{d\xi ^{2}} = \mu ^{2}\theta,$$

$$\frac{1}{\theta} \cdot d^2\theta = \mu^2 \cdot d^2\xi.$$

Can you take it from there?